# How to securely send an e-mail from client without exposing an XSS vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, java

We have a business application that can be considered legacy. As a part of this application, users can send a mail to their clients with one of our business e-mail accounts. The mail content is sent as html directly to the server, and sanitized using a white list.

However, our client wishes to install a WAF which blocks almost all of the html tags from reaching the server. This means that even if we were to encode the files, tags such as br, b or img get blocked. After a lot of back end forth, it was ultimately left to us to circumvent this issue. How can we alter this system so that it does not use html tags, even in encoded forms? The WAF blocks even the lt gt forms of these.

For reference, we use java 8 with javascript 1.7.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "alter this system"? And is sending text-only emails not an option?

Comment: We need to change it so that no html tags or their encoded forms get sent to the server. Text only is a no go as they do send image files encoded as base64, or links that need to be clicked. As the message goes as a reply to the previous mails, making it text only would remove the message history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AWS WAF V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and define the desired [WAF rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rules.html) with the rule builder wizard. The [text transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-transformation.html) rule statement (eg. HTML entity decode) has **nothing** to do with the [cross-site scripting attack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-xss-match.html) rule statement. Tearing down security measures is generally not suggested, while not know what one is actually doing. Using two separate hostnames might make it easier to tell apart these requests, in order to apply two different rule sets; see [how labeling works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-label-overview.html).

I mean, you could remove that HTML entity white list from the application and then declare it as a WAF rule statement instead - then WAF would sanitize the request, before it even hits the server. It is pointless to install WAF, but then not to configure and use it.

Comment: I just realised I mistakenly tagged the question as amazon-waf. I do not know which WAF they are using, but I will ask if we can use any form of text transform for this. Can you explain the last sentence a bit more? Are you suggesting we use a separate host for mail requests?

Comment: Unless you don't know which WAF they're using, this question is too abstract to answer. At least I've explained it, how it could be properly done with AWS WAF V2... and when applying labels, the logs are usually easier to understand.

Comment: The problem is that tag `waf` is unrelated and there's only [`amazon-waf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-waf). And if you cannot fit your question into the given content tags, it may well be considered as off-topic; despite they all work similar.